# Xamarin C# and Mobile Platforms

Tags: xamarin

I started Xamarin and I'm beginner. Since there is no documentation about Xamarin, when I have crash I can't find solution.

Anyway, I want to ask some question to you.

1. There are 2 choices: you can either use only Xamarin code with C# and this code yields to work with Android, IOS and Win Phone, or you can use separate code for Android, IOS and Win Phones. Is this information true or false? (I don't know I am exactly true.)
2. When I create a `.xaml` file with C# to yield Android, IOS and Win Phones, how can I use native pages, libraries (ex: SharedPreference). For example, I have a `.xaml` page and I want to navigate to an `Android.Activity` page - is this possible?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: "Since there is no documentation about Xamarin" !!!  https://developer.xamarin.com/

Comment: This is not sufficient to fix all crash, thank you  @CSharpRocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best friend for bugs and errors is google and stackoverflow. You can find almost everything as xamarin started to grow a lot after microsoft's acquisition.

1. You can either choose a unified solution like a PCL (Shared or Portable) or seperate projects.All of them are written in C# because that is what Xamarin is doing.
2. I don't think you have the ability to do that, but i am not sure.

You must do your research in order to find which way of coding is appropriate for your application. If you want to build something very unique with complex ui in each platform, you would probably choose separate projects. Else you can use xamarin forms to have a unique UI across all of your projects.